# CTeDistribuicaoDFe - Problemas ao consultar webservice

Tags: c#, .net, soap

Estou tentando consultar o `webservice` da Sefaz.

"https://www1.cte.fazenda.gov.br/CTeDistribuicaoDFe/CTeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx"

Estou recebendo o erro abaixo:

> "403 Forbidden - Access Denied".

A mensagem parece ser clara, mas estou passando um certificado digital válido.

Segue o trecho de código abaixo da chamada:

```
            var url = "https://www1.cte.fazenda.gov.br/CTeDistribuicaoDFe/CTeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx";
            var web = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            web.Method = "POST";
            web.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
            web.Accept = "text/xml";
            web.Headers.Clear();
            web.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", url);

            X509Certificate2 certificado = ObterCertificado();
            if (certificado != null)
            {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                web.ClientCertificates.Add(certificado);
            }

            var soap = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>";
            soap += "<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'>";
            soap += "<soap12:Body>";
            soap += "   <cteDistDFeInteresse xmlns='http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte/wsdl/CTeDistribuicaoDFe'>";
            soap += "       <distDFeInt xmlns='http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/cte' versao='1.00'>";
            soap += "           <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>";
            soap += "           <cUFAutor>91</cUFAutor>";
            soap += "           <CNPJ>00000000000000</CNPJ>";
            soap += "           <distNSU><ultNSU>000000000000000</ultNSU></distNSU>";
            soap += "       </distDFeInt>";
            soap += "   </cteDistDFeInteresse>";
            soap += "</soap12:Body>";
            soap += "</soap12:Envelope>";

            // soap = "<cteDadosMsg><distDFeInt xmlns='http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe' versao='1.00'><tpAmb>1</tpAmb><cUFAutor>35</cUFAutor><CNPJ>000000000000000</CNPJ><distNSU><ultNSU>000000000000002</ultNSU></distNSU></distDFeInt></cteDadosMsg>";

            var byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soap);
            web.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            using (var stream = web.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }

            using (var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)web.GetResponse())
            {
                using (var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    retorno = new StreamReader(stream).ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Fabio esse `layout` do `xml` está correto?

Comment: @JcSaint, na verdade, o problema estava no certificado digital mesmo. Não estava válido, acho que me passei nisso.

Comment: certo, é que meu `xml`de consulta é um pouco diferente...

Answer (score 1):

Esse layout retorna um HTTP response code 500, esta faltando a tag:

`<cteDadosMsg>xml</cteDadosMsg>`

Conforme a descrição do web-service: https://www1.cte.fazenda.gov.br/CTeDistribuicaoDFe/CTeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx?op=cteDistDFeInteresse